# How to pass a data from Node js to React or redirect a page from the sever

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, routes, stripe-payments

the final purpose is to redirect the payment page to the success page but that happens on the server and I got an object response from Stripe api which I would like to send it to the frontend(React) conditionally so I can redirect the page or do that directly from the backend Thanks

stripe button

```
     <div className={styles.buttonsection}>
    <StripeCheckout 
amount={total*100}
label="Credit Card"
name="Boston Maids"
email=""
token={ (token) =>{axios.post('/api/stripe', token)}} 

stripeKey={"*********************"}


/>
```

server.js

````
app.post('/api/stripe', async (req, res) => {

   const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 5000,
        currency: 'usd',
        description: 'Cleaning Services',
        source: req.body.id


    }).catch(console.error).then(charge =>{if (charge) {
     console.log(charge);

    } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method to call the backend API. On the success callback of that API, set the result in state and then process whatever you want to do.

Let us say, in the above example, if you want to populate the token, set the token from the result in the state and use `this.state.token` (if your state key is token for token from backend) as mentioned below:

```
<StripeCheckout 
amount={total*100}
label="Credit Card"
name="Boston Maids"
email=""
token={this.state.token} 
stripeKey={"pk_test_yBMj0cqYIXUsXeJ0lnVBil1T"}
/>
```

Comment: If you want redirection, you can render ```<Redirect />``` conditionally

Comment: Well make sense but I'm working with the other part. the above example is in the frontend, what I got to work with is the charge constant from the stripe request that happens in the backend(server.js) the above example happens first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just create a function outside the

````
```const handlerToken =  async (token, total2) => {


     const response = await axios.post("/api/stripe", {
        token,
        total2 ```



```  <StripeCheckout
                  amount={total * 100}
                  label="Credit Card"
                  name="Boston Maids"
                  email=""
                  token={handlerToken}
                  stripeKey={"*****************"}
                /> ```
````